# Relationship graph in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, nested-lists

I want to calculate number of friends for each person given a relationship graph **without using any libraries**. The graph is represented as lists of lists:

`graph = [[A,B],[A,C],[C,B],[B,D],[E]]`

Expected dictionary output: `{'A':2, 'B':3, 'C':2, 'D':1, 'E':0}`

Note: Since E has no friends, **E should be 0**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: Sound like a homework

Comment: It was an interview question @Alderven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Is there a better way to do this?

```
graph = [['A','B'],['A','C'],['C','B'],['B','D'],['E']]
dct ={}
for v in graph:
    for x in v:
            if x in v:
                    if x in dct.keys():
                            dct[x] += 1
                    else:
                            dct[x]= len(v)-1

print(dct)
{'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'E': 0}
```

Comment: `if x in v` is unnecessary. because `x in v` is always `True`. and you don't have to do `x in dct.keys()`. it's same as `x in dct`

Comment: ```graph = [['A','B'],['A','C'],['C','B'],['B','D'],['E']]
dct ={}
for v in graph:
    for x in v:
                if x in dct:
                        dct[x] += 1
                else:
                        dct[x]= len(v)-1

print(dct)
{'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'E': 0}```

Answer (score 4):

Straightforward solution without changing input format

```
>>> graph = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'],['C', 'B'], ['B', 'D'], ['E']]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> friends_counter = defaultdict(int)
>>> for friends in graph:
...     for person in friends:
...         friends_counter[person] += len(friends) - 1
>>> dict(friends_counter)
{'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'E': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a python library specific to graphs called [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html).  I changed the data to be easier to load.

```
import networkx as nx
graph = [['A','B'],['A','C'],['C','B'],['B','D']]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(graph)
G.add_node('E')

dict(G.degree)                                                         
#  {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'E': 0}
```

Edit: this answer was given before the "without using any libraries" caveat was added.

Comment: Agree, nextworkX suites best for this situation, don't know why @Kash refuse to use lib and like to rebuild wheels.

Comment: It was an interview question, that's why.

Comment: @Kash Ahh, that's a bad warning sign.  Try not to take the job.  If they are asking you to do interview questions without libraries the whole job might be like this.  They might have a problem with different software licenses (GPL etc..) or need you to make everything from scratch so they can have the IP (but then you will end up maintaining it as well).  It's a waste of your life.  You will be able to get more done elsewhere.  In the end you will need to balance how much you need cash with what type of impact you want to have as a software dev.

Answer (score -1):

so you can do like this

```
    graph = [["A","B"],["A","C"],["C","B"],["B","D"],["E"]]
    ans = {}
    for n in graph:
        if len(n) == 1:
                ans[n[0]] = ans.get(n[0], 0)
        else:
                l, r = n
                ans[l] = ans.get(l, 0) + 1
                ans[r] = ans.get(r, 0) + 1

    print(ans)
    # {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'E': 0}
```

Comment: Wrong answer again. E has no friends - should have 0 value.